# Upload from app service to azure blob workflow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a website running on azure app service, this website allow user to upload a file, after uploading to the server I take the stream and upload it to Azure blob storage.

```
blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
```

The website shows an upload progress percentage bar while the user is uploading the file.

So the workflow when user upload a file is:
- User upload a file (190MB for example takes 1 minute, based on user upload speed)
- Then when the server receive the file, it start uploading to the blob storage (it took 8 seconds for a 190MB)

Now my question is:
How to decrease these 8 seconds of waiting till the file get copied to the blob?
**Imaging the user is uploading a 1GB file

Options I thought about are:
- Let the user upload directly to the blob storage using js for example -> I can't use this option without changing a lot in the logic I have already.
- Upload the the server normally, save it in a temp folder then pass the file to a webjob or azure function to upload the file to the blob storage (feels like it will take more time than what is happening now)

Are there any other options I am missing?, or may be my whole workflow is not right

Comment: Try reading this article http://arcware.net/upload-and-download-files-with-web-api-and-azure-blob-storage/

Comment: @aaronR thank you, just finished reading it, it is good article, but this is somehow exactly what I am doing, he get the file(s) from the user to the server, save it as a local file then upload it back to azure storage so the time spent in this process is (Upload to server time + Upload from Server to blob storage)

Comment: So what type of client do you have?

Comment: @aaronR what do you mean by client? the user do you mean?

Comment: Is is web browser or native mobile app?

Comment: It is a website

Comment: Are the customers the general public or are they corporate in nature where they would have a good internet connection? Will the users be uploading files from their smart phones?

Comment: different type of users and yes they may upload from their phones, it is a public website, so I have no control of the users types.

Comment: So you are really limited by the users internet/cellular connection speed. What you could do is put the file upload logic into Azure functions so they won’t impact your other server functions/speed. I would do some do some baseline testing first on your configuration before trying to optimize.

Comment: But isn’t the azure functions way will be the same  work flow? Which is upload the file to the function then the function upload it back to the blob storage

Comment: It is but will scale and will allow your users to upload files without impacting each other or your main functions of your web app. And you only pay for what you use and first 1 million calls are free.

Comment: Make sure your web app has compression enabled too

Comment: Yes, you are right, all of these are very important and will improve my upload performance but will not affect the time of uploading from my app service to the blob storage, get me?

Comment: Hit me up on Twitter so we can talk further to get you a solution then share it with others. @cajunAA

Comment: This may be part of the solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Put-Block?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166198/discussion-between-amr-elgarhy-and-aaronr).